# How to get model map from model by key variable thymeleaf

Tags: java, thymeleaf

### > java controller code

```
import com.springboot.app.controllers.GlobalController;
import com.springboot.app.entities.Branch;
import com.springboot.app.services.ReportParamsAccessListService;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;

import org.springframework.ui.ModelMap;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;


import javax.persistence.Tuple;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.LinkedHashMap;
import java.util.List;

@Controller
public class GlobalReportController extends GlobalController {

    @Autowired
    ReportParamsAccessListService reportParamsAccessListService;



    protected  String branchParam(Model model,String paramName,String type, String name){
        ModelMap modelMap = new ModelMap();
        List<Branch> branchList = branchService.findAll();
        modelMap.put("branchList",branchList);
        modelMap.put("attr_name",name);
        modelMap.put("attr_type",type);
        model.addAttribute("branch",modelMap);
        return "branch_param";

    }

    protected  String dateParam(Model model,String paramName,String        type,String name){
        ModelMap modelMap = new ModelMap();
        modelMap.put("attr_name",name);
        modelMap.put("attr_type",type);
        model.addAttribute("date",modelMap);
        return "date_param";
    }


    @RequestMapping(value = "/report/test",method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public   String reportParams(Model model,String reportLink)   {
        LinkedHashMap<String,String> params = new LinkedHashMap<String, String>();
        List<Tuple> reportParamAccess =  reportParamsAccessListService.getReportParamAccess("reports/remittance_rub");
        for (int i = 0; i<reportParamAccess.size(); i++){
        try {
                String name =  reportParamAccess.get(i).get("name").toString();
                String paramName =  reportParamAccess.get(i).get("param_name").toString();
                String attrType = reportParamAccess.get(i).get("attr_type").toString();
                String attrName = reportParamAccess.get(i).get("attr_name").toString();
                switch (name){
                    case "branch":
                        params.put(paramName,branchParam(model,paramName,attrType,attrName));
                        break;
                    case "date":
                        params.put(paramName,dateParam(model,paramName,attrType,attrName));
                    default:
                }
             } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
         }
        //System.out.println("params  = "  + params);
        model.addAttribute("params",params);
        //System.out.println(" dataAlling = " + model);
        //return "report_params";
        return pageContent(model,"report_params");

    }


}
```

### > useing thymealeaf template engine

## > html code template brach param fragment

```
<div class="col-3"  xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org" th:fragment="branch_param">
 <div class="form-group" >
    <button type="button" id="dropdownUl" class="btn btn-info dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
        Select Branch
    </button>
    <div class="dropdown hide">
        <ul>
            <li th:each="branchList : ${branch.branchList}">
                <input th:id = "'md_checkbox_' + ${branchList.id}" th:type="${branch.attr_type}" th:value="${branchList.ip}" th:name="${branch.attr_name}"  class="filled-in chk-col-light-blue"  />
                <label th:for="'md_checkbox_' + ${branchList.id}"  th:text="${branchList.name}"></label>
            </li>

        </ul>
    </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

### > html code template report params fragment

```
<ul  xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org" th:fragment="report_params">
    <li th:each="paramEntry : ${params}">
      <div th:include="${paramEntry.value} :: ${paramEntry.value}" th:with="ParamName=${paramEntry.key}">

      </div>


    </li>

</ul>
```

### > html code template date params fragment

```
<div class="col-2"  xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org" th:fragment="date_param">
    <div class="form-group" >
       <input  th:type="${date.attr_type}"  th:name="${date.attr_name}"  class="form-control"  />
    </div>
</div>
```

> **I want pass variable ParamName from report params to branch param and date param then use ParamName in fragments 
>   for example like this in branch param**

```
<div class="col-3"  xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org" th:fragment="branch_param">
     <div class="form-group" >
        <button type="button" id="dropdownUl" class="btn btn-info dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
            Select Branch
        </button>
        <div class="dropdown hide">
            <ul>
                <li th:each="branchList : ${ParamName.branchList}">
                    <input th:id = "'md_checkbox_' + ${branchList.id}" th:type="${branch.attr_type}" th:value="${branchList.ip}" th:name="${branch.attr_name}"  class="filled-in chk-col-light-blue"  />
                    <label th:for="'md_checkbox_' + ${branchList.id}"  th:text="${branchList.name}"></label>
                </li>

            </ul>
        </div>
     </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Hi. You'll get better answers if you make it easier to read - I've fixed the code formatting to show you how. I recommend you also to add a code snippet showing what you want to do, it's not quite clear from your explanation.

Comment: Please post your complete Controller/View Template code. At least just the Controller Method part in its entirety.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is done by [preprocessing](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/2.1/usingthymeleaf.html#preprocessing) mechanism in Thymeleaf

Here is a snippet of what you want to do:

```
<li th:each="branchList : ${__${paramName}__.branchList}">
```